Netbeans cannot start after updating to Kubuntu 24.10
Netbeans cannot start after updating to Kubuntu 24.10.
From the menu, from the command line, previous versions even AppImage… On X11 and Wayland… After deleting .netbeans folder… with openjdk and Oracle Java…
Sometimes the splash screen shows without the standard info – just as a gray block.
When running it from the terminal I got some warnings:
Detected KDE; use explicit setting for font antialiasing (-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd_hrgb)
WARNING: package com.apple.eio not in java.desktop
WARNING: package com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows not in java.desktop
WARNING: package com.apple.laf not in java.desktop
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager (file:/usr/lib/apache-netbeans/platform/lib/boot.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release

In sysmon the process appears for a minute or two and then ends quietly.
